# How to make a SQL Server agent job step failure on purpose

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-job

I have a process and the first step is to check status of other process. If the other process is done I would want to run the rest steps and if not I would want to quit the job.

I have a table that looks into the status and if all done it will mark as 'done'. So what should I put in the first step so that when the status is not 'done', it makes step 1 fail?

Comment: so you want SQL that always gives an error?  such as 'select (Select 1 union SELECT 2) X'

Comment: `RAISERROR ('Fail!', 16, 1)`

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of ways you can force sql-server to throw (or raise) an error but I would recommend using THROW for SQL-Server 2012 + or RAISERROR below that as that is your actual intention.  So you could do something like:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM StatusTable WHERE status <> 'done')
BEGIN
    ;THROW 51000, 'Process Is Not Finished', 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also "Select 1/0" this will parse but it will giving error while execution

Comment: That is what try/catch is for.  Using 1/0 is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it is bad practice to fail a job-step to implement application logic. Better to use IF (some condition) THEN (some job-step action) ELSE (print an explanation why there was no job-step action). And reserve failures for operational issues.

Comment: Think bigger, when you have several steps, after a specific one, that you do not want to run if this one is considered to be a job stop criteria. Failing a job is normal practice, that is why there is settings per step to tell it what to do upon success or failure.